# cannot get mailbox folder permissions of a specific contact group using powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, contacts

First I want to show you all the folders that are contained within a mailbox called "ssc.public"

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailboxfolderstatistics ssc.public | select Identity

Identity
--------
ssc.public\Top of Information Store
ssc.public\Calendar
ssc.public\Calendar\Boardroom
ssc.public\Calendar\Meeting room
ssc.public\Contacts
ssc.public\Contacts\A1 FOOD & COFFEE OPERATORS
ssc.public\Contacts\ACCOUNTANTS
ssc.public\Contacts\ADVERTISING
ssc.public\Contacts\ARCHITECTS
ssc.public\Contacts\BANKS & RECEIVERS
ssc.public\Contacts\BINGO
ssc.public\Contacts\BOWLING
ssc.public\Contacts\CASINO
ssc.public\Contacts\CHEFS
ssc.public\Contacts\CHILDREN'S ENTERTAINMENT
ssc.public\Contacts\CINEMAS
ssc.public\Contacts\CLUBS & LATE NIGHT VENUES
ssc.public\Contacts\COFFEE LIST
ssc.public\Contacts\COMPLETELY RETAIL MARKET LIST
ssc.public\Contacts\DEVELOPERS INVESTORS & FREE HOLD PURCHASERS
ssc.public\Contacts\FINE DINING
ssc.public\Contacts\GASTRO PUB OPERATORS
ssc.public\Contacts\HEALTH & FITNESS
ssc.public\Contacts\HOTELIERS & HOTELS
ssc.public\Contacts\INDEPENDENT KIOSK OPERATORS
ssc.public\Contacts\INDEPENDENT OPERATORS-
ssc.public\Contacts\INSOLVENCY PRACTITIONER
ssc.public\Contacts\JOURNALISTS
ssc.public\Contacts\LANDLORD'S & SCHEME OWNERS
ssc.public\Contacts\LATE NIGHT LICENCE
ssc.public\Contacts\LEISURE & A3 AGENTS
ssc.public\Contacts\MULTIPLE RESTAURANT OWNERS
ssc.public\Contacts\NO CATEGORY
ssc.public\Contacts\OPERATORS
ssc.public\Contacts\PRESS RELEASE LIST
ssc.public\Contacts\PUBS & BARS
ssc.public\Contacts\SOLICITORS
ssc.public\Contacts\SUPPLIERS
ssc.public\Contacts\SURVEYORS
ssc.public\Conversation Action Settings
ssc.public\Deleted Items
ssc.public\Drafts
ssc.public\Inbox
ssc.public\Journal
ssc.public\Junk E-Mail
ssc.public\News Feed
ssc.public\Notes
ssc.public\Outbox
ssc.public\Quick Step Settings
ssc.public\RSS Feeds
ssc.public\Sent Items
ssc.public\Suggested Contacts
ssc.public\Tasks
ssc.public\Recoverable Items
ssc.public\Deletions
ssc.public\Purges
ssc.public\Versions
```

This command runs fine if I try to see the permissions of Contacts\BOWLING folder

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailboxfolderpermission ssc.public:\Contacts\BOWLING


    RunspaceId   : 47fbeee1-6217-46e7-b34e-50ed7223dee8
    FolderName   : BOWLING
    User         : Default
    AccessRights : {Reviewer}
    Identity     : Default
    IsValid      : True
```

Why doesn't it work if I do the same with Contacts\BINGO folder?

```
 [PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailboxfolderpermission  ssc.public:\Contacts\BINGO
 The operation couldn't be performed because 'ssc.public:\Contacts\BINGO' couldn't be found.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MailboxFolderPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 4ECD0424,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.GetMailboxFolderPermission
```

Comment: Try enumerating contacts, then get name from out there. I've met people who used different layouts with some letters in a single word. "O" might be non-English.

Comment: Vesper, to be honest with you I don't know how to enumerate contacts, any further suggestion?

Comment: Selecting `Identity` counts as enumeration,

Comment: Tried that, It still doesn't work at all...
Can anyone help me with this one, please?

Comment: I have just noticed that if I check the permissions for "CHILDREN'S ENTERTAINMENT" I get the same error

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailboxfolderpermission ssc.public:\Contacts\"CHILDREN'S ENTERTAINMENT"
The operation couldn't be performed because 'ssc.public:\Contacts\CHILDREN'S ENTERTAINMENT' couldn't be found.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MailboxFolderPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 634CA76A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.GetMailboxFolderPermission

Comment: Probably you don't have permissions to see the folder. You need to get full mailbox access permissions for the account that's used to launch that script, and check again.

Comment: same thing as well if I try to get the permissions of "SUPPLIERS", I don't get why it doesn't find it.

Comment: I am running the script as administrator.

Comment: Check from Outlook, maybe there's corruption or custom non-inherited permissions on the mailbox's folders.

Comment: I checked from Outlook, what I did was to rename the actual folders that were creating conflict "BINGO, CHILDREN'S ENTERTAINMENT and SUPPLIERS". Afterwards I renamed them one more time to their original name. Now it works. I hate not understanding why it didn't work in the first place. I'm afraid that I will have the same issue in the future when I'll try to check another mailbox's contacts permissions. I won't be able to automate this whole process if I have to amend certain contacts folder names by hand.

Comment: Unlikely, in fact, but if you'd rename and the problem won't go away, feel free to ask.